# $AB$ and $BA$ do not have the same eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $A$ is $n\times m$ and $B$ is $m\times n$ where $n\not = m$.
>   Show $AB$ and $BA$ may not have the same eigenvalues.

Can someone offer me a simple counterexample for this claim? Is it required to prove the statement for all $n,m$, or can a counterexample be used?

Comment: If you write down random matrices, they should do the job. Have you tried anything? A counterexample would suffice, yes.

Comment: Try some smaller $n$ and $m$: for example, $m=1$ and $n=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial case: $A = \pmatrix{1\\0}$, $B = A^T$ then
$$AB = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$$
with eigenvalues $1$ and $0$ and
$$BA = 1$$
with eigenvalue $1$ (seen as a $1\times 1$ matrix).

Answer (score 5):

Hint: They actually have the same **nonzero** eigenvalues.  Look for a small example where one of $AB$ and $BA$ is invertible.  The other will not be invertible.